# How to setup animation with device to device with the help of firebase database or other?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-animation

I built a chat android app using firebase database. Now i want to update with some animation feature.
The concept is , animation will animate whenever user click on animation button in current user device and receiver device.

for this current user set the values in firebase

```
"isAnimate":true
```

otherwise it already set

```
"isAnimate":false
```

Now receiver get this value by `addValueEventListener` and show animation on their device.

Now the question is, animation animate rate is 10 times per 1 second(Maximum click per second up to user), so firebase can able to change data from *false* to *true* 10 times per second and for the receiver can `onDataChange` get data 10 times per 1 second ? if yes than firebase costing tends to too high and if No, than please suggest something like this concept .

1. User A:click button for animation and in firebase set value from false to true. and after animation complete set value from true to false
2. User B: run inbuilt animation if value is true in firebase.

Comment: Why would you update 10 times the value in Firebase?

Comment: than how receiver will get animation if current user dont update

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what are you trying to achieve. #1 User A click animate. #2 Update animation active in firebase #3 User B observes change #4 When value is set, run animation on user B device.

Comment: 1. User A ,click button for animation
2. User B. show inbuilt animation with help of firebase

Comment: I think what you need is not a `Boolean` value but a random `String` value. #1 User A click animate #2 Set `isAnimate: "myRan0mStringGenerated"`. 3# User B observers `isAnimate` #4 If `isAnimate` have changed, play animation. No further update is required. You can repeat this endlessly

Comment: please see my corrected question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207333/discussion-between-user11276659-and-parohy).